# tikz positioning. How to place a node below of another only by y coordinate, leaving x alone

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I have 2 chains in different columns of a table. I need to shift the second chain in a such way that the `{mv r0 <- a}` would be below the `{br a = 0 $end}`, as it is depicted : right below the red line.

How to do it without inserting a fake node and adjusting its length?

[image: Desired position]

EDIT[as @Werner suggested]: Here is the code to reproduce the example. In the picture above, the right column is allready shifted by a graphical editor, originally they were aligned.

```
\newcommand*{\ld}[2]{ld\ #1\gets \$#2}
\newcommand*{\st}[2]{st\ #1\to \$#2}
\newcommand*{\add}[2]{add\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\mul}[2]{mul\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\mov}[2]{mv\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\inc}[1]{inc\ #1}
\newcommand*{\brz}[2]{br\ #1=0\ \$#2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[-,auto,
up/.style={draw=none,above=.5cm},
down/.style={draw=none,below=.5cm},
long/.style={minimum height=2.5cm}]
\matrix [matrix,row sep=0.2cm,nodes={draw,font=\footnotesize},every even column/.style={text centered,text width=2.3cm}]
{
    \node (up1)[up]{};&&\node(up2)[up]{};&&\node (up3)[up]{};&&\node(up4)[up]{};&\\
&\begin{scope}
    [node distance=1mm, start chain=going below];
    \node [anchor=north, on chain] {$\inc a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld a a$};
    \node [on chain] {$\brz a{end}$};
    \node [on chain] {$\inc a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld a a$};
    \node [on chain] {$\brz a{end}$};
\end{scope}&
&\begin{scope}
    [node distance=1mm, start chain=going below];
    \node [anchor=north, on chain] {$\mov {r_0}a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld {r_1} {r_0}$};
    \node [on chain] {$\mul {r_1}{r_1*r_1}$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\st {r_1} {r_0}$};
\end{scope}\\
    \node (down1)[down]{};&&\node (down2)[down]{};&&\node(down3)[down]{};&&\node(down4)[down]{};&\\
};
\begin{scope}
\draw (up1) to (down1);
\draw (up2) to (down2);
\draw (up3) to (down3);
\draw (up4) to (down4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: How does it work? Are these sites connected in some way? Why I don't logged in there if it is so?

Comment: @Necto: Don't worry about it. Site moderators will move this for you. It would help though if you could include that generated the above output. That way community members can tackle the problem without trying to recreate it first.

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `at` option combined with a named chain gives a solution: first chain is named `ch`; first node of second chain is north anchored `at` north of fourth node of first chain (`ch-4.north`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\ld}[2]{ld\ #1\gets \$#2}
\newcommand*{\st}[2]{st\ #1\to \$#2}
\newcommand*{\add}[2]{add\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\mul}[2]{mul\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\mov}[2]{mv\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\inc}[1]{inc\ #1}
\newcommand*{\brz}[2]{br\ #1=0\ \$#2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[-,auto,
up/.style={draw=none,above=.5cm},
down/.style={draw=none,below=.5cm},
long/.style={minimum height=2.5cm}]
\matrix [matrix,row sep=0.2cm,nodes={draw,font=\footnotesize},every even column/.style={text centered,text width=2.3cm}]
{
    \node (up1)[up]{};&&\node(up2)[up]{};&&\node (up3)[up]{};&&\node(up4)[up]{};&\\
   &\begin{scope}
    [node distance=1mm, start chain=ch going below];
    \node [on chain] {$\inc a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld a a$};
    \node [on chain] {$\brz a{end}$};
    \node [on chain] {$\inc a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld a a$};
    \node [on chain] {$\brz a{end}$};
\end{scope}&
&\begin{scope}
    [node distance=1mm, start chain=going below];
    \node [on chain,anchor=north,at={(ch-4.north)}] {$\mov {r_0}a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld {r_1} {r_0}$};
    \node [on chain] {$\mul {r_1}{r_1*r_1}$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\st {r_1} {r_0}$};
\end{scope}\\
    \node (down1)[down]{};&&\node (down2)[down]{};&&\node(down3)[down]{};&&\node(down4)[down]{};&\\
};
\begin{scope}
\draw (up1) to (down1);
\draw (up2) to (down2);
\draw (up3) to (down3);
\draw (up4) to (down4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think, that "at" can work in such complicated manner. (sorry for confusion)

Comment: In fact, this solution works only because each cell of the matrix is (re)positioned *after* its contents is computed. Outside of a matrix, the two chains are superimposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matrix of nodes` key to remove the additional `\node` declarations in the matrix cells. Also you can anchor the scope such that it is handled from that declared point lastly you can always shift your node around with a `cm={a,b,c,d,(coord1,coord2}` to scale with the `[xnew;ynew] = [a,c;b,d]*[x;y] + [coord1;coord2]` transformation matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\newcommand*{\ld}[2]{ld\ #1\gets \$#2}
\newcommand*{\st}[2]{st\ #1\to \$#2}
\newcommand*{\add}[2]{add\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\mul}[2]{mul\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\mov}[2]{mv\ #1\gets #2}
\newcommand*{\inc}[1]{inc\ #1}
\newcommand*{\brz}[2]{br\ #1=0\ \$#2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[-,auto,
up/.style={draw=none,above=.5cm},
down/.style={draw=none,below=.5cm},
long/.style={minimum height=2.5cm}]
\matrix [row sep=0.2cm,nodes={draw,font=\footnotesize},every even column/.style={text centered,text width=2.3cm}]
{
    \node (up1)[up]{};&&\node(up2)[up]{};&&\node (up3)[up]{};&&\node(up4)[up]{};&\\
&\begin{scope}
    [node distance=1mm, start chain=going below];
    \node [anchor=north, on chain] {$\inc a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld a a$};
    \node [on chain] {$\brz a{end}$};
    \node [on chain] (inca) {$\inc a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld a a$};
    \node [on chain] {$\brz a{end}$};
\end{scope}&
&\begin{scope}[anchor=north west,cm={1,0,0,1,(inca.north east)},
    node distance=1mm, start chain=going below];
    \node [anchor=north, on chain] {$\mov {r_0}a$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\ld {r_1} {r_0}$};
    \node [on chain] {$\mul {r_1}{r_1*r_1}$};
    \node [on chain, long] {$\st {r_1} {r_0}$};
\end{scope}\\
    \node (down1)[down]{};&&\node (down2)[down]{};&&\node(down3)[down]{};&&\node(down4)[down]{};&\\
};
\begin{scope}
\draw (up1) to (down1);
\draw (up2) to (down2);
\draw (up3) to (down3);
\draw (up4) to (down4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the mess. I've mixed the answers.

Comment: A'm aware of "matrix of nodes" but I could not make it work with chains.